# Explanation of the outout of lsperf, a logstash performance testing tool

Tags: logstash

I am trying to use [lsperfm](https://github.com/elastic/logstash-performance-testing), a logstash peformance testing tool. I have followed their installation instructions as mentioned in the README.md in their github wiki. I have logstash 1.5.2 installed in logstash 1.5.2/.

I faced a problem in the bootstrap step as mentioned in the README.md in their [github](https://github.com/elastic/logstash-performance-testing) wiki. After executing `rake bootstrap` and `lsperfm-deps` when I tried to execute `bin/logstash deps` it threw me an error

`No such command "deps"`.

Other than this the installation went fine.

On executing `lsperm` from my logstash root directory. I got the below output:-

```
simple line in/out,7.94,120.33,2688000,22339,28700.00,27043
simple line in/json out,13.03,120.32,2682000,22291,29600.00,27300
json codec in/out,8.65,120.04,1896000,15795,19500.00,18652
line in/json filter/json out,7.96,120.18,1398000,11633,17200.00,14226
apache in/json out,8.37,120.08,2372040,19755,28000.00,26260
apache in/grok codec/json out,7.82,120.11,1051380,8753,11000.00,10365
syslog in/json out,9.14,120.81,294000,2434,3000.00,2882
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered by Pere Ubron [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/ouput-explanation-of-lsperfm-logstash-performance-testing/25281) . Reposting it below:-

> Thanks for testing this gem, however I must tell you nowadays this is
>   still experimental, so things can change a lot till version 1.0 smile .
>
> Regarding the installation procedures, this part is completely
>   misleading, thanks for noticing the bug. `bin/logstash` deps is only for
>   versions before `1.5`. This is why you are able to run the test without
>   problems.
>
> Regarding the output, this is a bug, you should see explanatory
>   headers, but the output is missing them. I will explain, briefly what
>   they are here in order as they appear:
>
> - The name of the test.
> - The time necessary to bootstrap/start logstash for this test.
> - How long the test was running.
> - Number of events processed.
> - Average events per second during the test.
> - Best events per second during the test.
> - Top 20% average events per second during the test.
>
> As you could imagine this is basically feeding different data and
>   different configurations to Logstash to then get some numbers out. You
>   can see the configurations used inside the defaults directory.
>
> /cheers
>
> purbon